# How do I append a value from an object I'm iterating to the ASP.NET control ID

Tags: asp.net

I want to accomplish the following

```
<ul>
<% foreach (var foo in foos) { %>
    <li><input id="foo<%=foo.Bar %>" runat="server" type="checkbox"/></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

But it gives me the error

> Error 2   'foo<%=foo.Bar %>' is not a valid identifier.

EDIT:

This seems to work, but of course I don't get access to the checkboxes in the code-behind. I have to use JavaScript

```
<ul>
<% foreach (var foo in foos) { %>
    <li><input id="<%="foo" + foo.Bar %>" type="checkbox"/></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix inline code (<%= %>) with server controls.  Try using a Repeater control and data events to dynamically control the row-by-row output.